# Oracle SQL trigger with JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE of ON TABLE_NAME 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    if inserting then
        if :new.col_a < (select col_b from table_a natural join table_b where some_col = :new.some_value)
            then
            raise_application_error(-20000, 'Raise some error');
        end if;
    end if;
END;
```

when I try to compile I get this error

> Error(6,93): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JOIN" when expecting
> one of the following:     ) , with group having intersect minus start
> union where    connect The symbol "," was substituted for "JOIN" to
> continue.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the `JOIN` that causes the error, but the fact that usage of a subquery is invalid in this context. Select value first (out of `IF`), use it later. Something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
   BEFORE INSERT
   --OR UPDATE of    --> of what?
   ON table_name
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   l_col_b  table_b.col_b%TYPE;
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING
   THEN
      SELECT col_b
        INTO l_col_b
        FROM table_a NATURAL JOIN table_b
       WHERE some_col = :new.some_value;

      IF :new.col_a < l_col_b
      THEN
         raise_application_error (-20000, 'Raise some error');
      END IF;
   END IF;
END;
```

Also, use table aliases. It is impossible to know which column belongs to which table. Furthermore, your trigger wants to fire before `update of` ... what? I commented it out.